# Configurations of deficiency $k$ where any of $k$ lines parallel to a given line are also parallel to each other

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

Given a combinatorial configuration of points and lines with deficiency $k$, each line is parallel/non-intersecting with $k$ other lines.

What is known about configurations where these $k$ other lines also happen to be parallel to each other?

This is trivially true for projective planes and when $k=1$, but not guaranteed for $k\geq 2$.